# How to Get @@ROWCOUNT from a Single Query in a UNION - Create Trailer record with RowCount

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a HEADER and a TRAILER record. The **TRAILER needs to include the RowCount of the 'main' query**. How Can I get the @@Rowcount of the query and save it to variable , to be included in the TRAILER.

See this.

```
--- Var to save Count

declare @cnt int

-- HEADER RECORD
Select Cast('H' as Char(2)) +
    Cast('MyFile' as Char(30))
    + CONVERT(Char(8),GetDate(),112)

union all

-- MAIN Query that I need the Count of

Select top 10 lastname from CUSTOMERS

set @cnt = @@ROWCOUNT

union all    <--ERROR obviously

-- TRAILER record  
Select Cast('T' as Char(2)) +
         CONVERT(Char(9),GetDate(),112) +
      Right(Replicate('0',9) + Cast(@cnt as VarChar(9)),9)
```

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CTE to reuse the definition of the main query:

```
WITH Query AS (
    SELECT top 10 lastname from CUSTOMERS
)
SELECT X.Result
FROM (
    SELECT Cast('H' as Char(2)) + Cast('MyFile' as Char(30)) 
        + CONVERT(Char(8),GetDate(),112) AS Result, 1 AS Position
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 2 AS Position FROM Query
    UNION ALL
    Select Cast('T' as Char(2)) + CONVERT(Char(9),GetDate(),112) + Right(Replicate('0',9) 
        + Cast((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Query) as VarChar(9)),9) AS Result, 3 AS Position
) X ORDER BY X.Position
```

However, the CTE will be evaluated twice; if your query is complex and time-consuming, you might want to use a temporary table:

```
SELECT TOP 10 lastname INTO #Temp FROM CUSTOMERS

SELECT X.Result
FROM (
    SELECT Cast('H' as Char(2)) + Cast('MyFile' as Char(30))
         + CONVERT(Char(8),GetDate(),112) AS Result, 1 AS Position
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 2 AS Position FROM #Temp
    UNION ALL
    Select Cast('T' as Char(2)) + CONVERT(Char(9),GetDate(),112) + Right(Replicate('0',9) 
         + Cast((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp) as VarChar(9)),9) AS Result, 3 AS Position
) X ORDER BY X.Position
```

Comment: One more thing: `UNION ALL` does not guarantee ordering. If you want the header row to be the first and the trailer row to be the last, you need to specify that in an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this following script-

```
-- HEADER RECORD
SELECT CAST('H' AS CHAR(2)) + CAST('MyFile' AS CHAR(30)) + CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)

UNION ALL

-- MAIN Query that I need the Count of
SELECT lastname FROM CUSTOMERS

UNION ALL

-- TRAILER record  
SELECT CAST('T' AS CHAR(2)) + CONVERT(CHAR(9), GETDATE(), 112) + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 9) + CAST(
(
    SELECT COUNT(lastname) FROM CUSTOMERS
) AS VARCHAR(9)), 9);
```